# Documenting Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, documentation

I am looking for the best practices while documenting code in JavaScript or React components. What is out there that can be considered as "nice tools/libraries" while documenting? 
Thanks.

Comment: this might help: https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/documenting.html

Answer (score 6):

For JavaScript during a long time and still used currently there is [JSdoc3](https://jsdoc.app/).

> JSDoc 3 is an API documentation generator for JavaScript, similar to Javadoc or phpDocumentor. You add documentation comments directly to your source code, right alongside the code itself. The JSDoc tool will scan your source code and generate an HTML documentation website for you.

But it looks like the support on this repository looks dead currently but it's still used by a lot of people.

Other alternatives there is :

- [yuidoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/)

  > YUIDoc is a Node.js application that generates API documentation from comments in source, using a syntax similar to tools like Javadoc and Doxygen.
- [apidoc](http://apidocjs.com/) (But more focused for RESTful API)

  > Inline Documentation for RESTful web APIs
  >   apiDoc creates a documentation from API annotations in your source code.

---

Now if you are looking for something more integrated with React/Components and a playground where users can play around with and view live code there is other choices (more oriented UI Components) :

- [React Styleguidist](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/)

  > Isolated React component development environment with a living style guide
- [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/)

  > Storybook is a UI development environment and playground for UI components. The tool enables users to create components independently and showcase components interactively in an isolated development environment.
- [Docz](https://www.docz.site/introduction)

  > Today, tools that allow us to be quick and effective in what we are doing are really necessary. We can't afford to lose time with tasks that should be trivial. This is why docz was created.

Docz and Styleguidist both have a playgrounds where users can play around with and view live code and automatic proptables that read out component proptypes. Documentation are written in MDX file for the first one and simple markdown for the second.
Docz may be the easiest one to use but they can all fit your needs.

For Storybook I know it's a great tool but I never used it so I can tell you more about it.

JSDocs could also be used for documenting components but without interactive state.

Comment: Storybook seems to be more about creating UI than documenting code and generating documentation.

Comment: @FMaz008 Definitely ! Storybook is not used to document code. It's useful, if you want to explain how to use components, by adding documentation and displaying the available properties you can use with it.